# removing dynamically created <div> triggered from Google map marker click

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3, dynamic-data

From the digging I've done it looks like I want to use .on but I'm note sure how to go about implementing it. I'm still learning javascript and jquery so I could be missing something...

The code below runs when a marker is added to a Google map (v3 api). It creates a marker and adds a form field. If the user then clicks on the newly created marker the marker is hidden and the code should then remove the form  as well. The marker removes fine but I can't get the  removed. This is the line I'm looking for help with:

```
    $('#newdiv + site_count).remove();
```

If i manually replace newdiv+ site_count with a valid number (say 6 so newdiv6) the code works I just can't figure out how to reference it live... Finally here is the rest of the relevant code:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function(event) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: event.latLng,
      map: map
    });
    newlocation = "<div id='newdiv" + site_count + "'><input type='text' size='3' name='loc[" + site_count + "]' id='newid" + site_count + "' value = '0' /></div>";
                $('#here').append(newlocation)
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function(event) {
                marker.setVisible(false);
                $('#new+ site_count).remove(); 
        });
        site_count++;        


})
```

Thanks for taking the time to have a look at my issue.
--AJ

Comment: Dealing with the syntax errors would probably help. :-)

Comment: I try to understand why u want to do: drop new marker on map and drag it to other place, right?

Comment: Thanks for looking at this. I have a form which includes a google map. I want to add hidden form fields for the data points (markers) added to the map. I can add hidden fields fine but if the user wants to change them (delete) I can remove the map point fine but I can't seem to find the added form fields (via code) to remove them from the form.

Answer (score 2):

This line

```
$('#new+ site_count).remove();
```

has three issues:

1. There's no closing `'`, so it causes a syntax error.
2. You're giving the `div` containing the form fields the ID `newsiteX`, but that line is trying to find it using the ID `newX` instead.
3. After creating your new `div`, you're incrementing `site_count`, but later you're trying to find the div using the *new* value of `site_count`, and so you won't. That is, if `site_count` is `0` and you create a new div, it'll have the `id` `"newsite0"` and `site_count` will get incremented to `1`. Then when you go to remove it on click, even if you fix the items above, you'll be looking for `newsite1` rather than `newsite0`.

You haven't shown enough of your code for me to confidently correct it for you, but probably something along these lines:

```
$('#newsite' + (site_count - 1)).remove();
```

That said, you may want to step back and take a deeper look at the structure, this seems a bit fragile (but may be fine).

Comment: I agree with your fix, question (since u have 160k, lol) why do not use draw manager, add marker to manager, create some form and bind with marker and on click remove all bineded forms + marker itself from the map. I know u did find the issue into his code but sounds like the way he tried to implement specific logic is too complicated

Comment: @MaximShoustin: I haven't used the relevant API. If you have, and can give him a better approach (and if you think that's an answer to his question), you should post it -- maybe it'll help! :-)